# где ошибка в коде ? не могу найти

Tags: python

```
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "ничья"
NUM_SQUARES = 9

def display_instruct():
    """Выводит инструкцию для игрока"""
    print(
    """
    добро пожаловать в игру крестики-нолики сдесь вы будите играть с ИИ
    вы должни победить его и доказать свое право на существование
    поле для игры
    +---+---+---+
    | 0 | 1 | 2 |
    +---+---+---+
    | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    +---+---+---+
    | 6 | 7 | 8 |
    +---+---+---+
    \n
    """
    )
# основная часть
print("это инструкция для игры в X-O")
display_instruct()
print("надеюсь все понятно")

def ask_yes_no(question):
    """ задает вопрос с ответом да или нет """
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
        return response


def ask_number(question, low, high):
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response


def pieces():
    """ определяет принадлежность первого хода """
    go_first = ask_yes_no("хочешь ходить первым? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nНу что же даю тебе фору:  играйте крестиками")
        human = "X"
        computer = "O"
    else :
        print("\nТвоя удаль тебя погубит... Буду начинать я")
        computer = "X"
        human = "O"
        return computer, human


def new_board():
    """ Создает новую игровую доску """
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board
def display_board(board):
    """ Отображает игровую доску """
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "----------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "----------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8])
def legal_moves(board):
    """ Создает список доступных ходов """
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves
def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0,1,2),
                    (3,4,5),
                    (6,7,8),
                    (0,3,6),
                    (1,4,7),
                    (2,5,8),
                    (0,4,8),
                    (2,4,6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
        return None
def human_move(board, human):
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Твой ход. выбери одно из полей (0 - 8): ", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nЭто поле уже занято")
    print("ладно...")
    return move
def computer_move(board, human, computer):
    """  Делает ход за ПК пр """
    board = board[:]
    BEST_MOVES = (4,0,2,6,8,1,3,5,7)
    print("Я беру поле номером", end = " ")
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move
def next_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X
def congrat(theWinner, computer, human):
    if theWinner != TIE:
        print("три " , theWinner, "в ряд")
    else:
        print(TIE)
    if theWinner == computer:
        print("выиграл ПК")
    elif theWinner == human:
        print("Выиграл Человек")
    elif theWinner == TIE:
        print("ничья")
def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn  = next_turn(turn)
    theWinner = winner(board)
    congrat(theWinner, computer, human)
main()
```

не понимаю почему не работает когда нижимаю на y

Comment: Табуляция в нескольких местах нарушена. А именно: return в ask_yes_no на один влево, return в pieces тоже на один таб влево

Comment: Какое поведение вы ожидаете?

Comment: Если у вас появляется ошибка, ее текст желательно приводить в вопросе. Тут сразу можно сказать, что в функции `pieces` `return` спрятан в блоке `else`. Соответственно, при выполнении условия, функция вернет `None`, что приведет к ошибке.

Comment: все поправил, но не определяется победитель!